# How can I download macOS Catalina on a 2011 Mac mini that doesn't support it?

Tags: macos, catalina, mac-appstore

Note:  I only want to download it, **not** install it on the 2011!

The App store doesn't let me download it, but I don't want to install it, I just want to download it and create an USB installer so I can restore my other Mac.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 9):

You can use [Dosdude1's Catalina patcher](http://dosdude1.com/catalina/) to download the official Catalina installer from Apple's servers.

*Disclaimer: I'm not a fan of bodging macOS to work on unsupported platforms, especially for "production" machines.  However, if you're looking to tinker and this is something to experiment with to learn, I say have at it.  If you need the latest OS for work, get a machine that supports it.*

Basically, what you're going to do is trick macOS and ultimately Apple's servers into believing that your machine is capable of running Catalina so it will download.

When you run the Patcher, make sure you uncheck "Auto-apply Post Install Patches" found in the Options menu."  This is because you're not installing Catalina onto this Mac; all you want to do is get the installer so you can create the USB Installer.

Once you will get to a screen where you can either browse for an installer or download a copy, select the download option.

[image: Catalina Patcher Install Screen]

Download the DMG, it will be approximately 7GB. From there, you can make your offline installer.  The Terminal command is as follows:

```
sudo /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Catalina.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/Catalina --nointeraction
```

If this worked out for you, I encourage you to buy him a coffee or a beer (or maybe even dinner) by sending a donation his way (I'm not affiliated, I just appreciate people's hard work).  You'll find the "donate" link on the software download page.

Comment: To add to Allan's answer, since you are just wanting to create an USB Installer, watch the Tutorial Video starting at about the 6 minute mark. https://youtu.be/wxFzZWqoCng?t=358

Comment: Thanks, I just tried it and the download failed in the middle. Also found _gibMacOS_ that apparently does the same, although it's taking forever to download.  
Will try this, thanks!

Comment: @Petruza Downloads failing halfway through isn't unusual in this case. The slightest hickup in you internet connection may cause this. In my experience the download process doesn't handle network hiccups very well and easily aborts in stead of retrying and continuing. You may to try a couple of time before it succeeds.

Comment: @Tonny, And that is why I would not use this method and instead use a virtual machine running an appropriate version of the OS that will allow the download thru normal Apple methods, which will typically recover from a network hiccup.

Comment: I haven't tried it...can you run a version of macOS that's unsupported natively on a host running VM software (Parallels, VBox, VMware).  Can you run Mojave/Catalina in a VBox VM that's on a Sierra host?  (I don't have the hardware to try it out).

Comment: @user3439894 This is the normal Apple download process. And a VM doesn't make any difference. I've had OS downloads hiccup many times on supported hardware as well. Besides that... Running MacOS in a VM has it own problems. VirtualBox is extremely difficult to get to work and is very slow. VMware performance was (last time I tried) even worse. Only Parallels works reasonably well, but is expensive and as Allan also says, I'm not all that sure you can run a newer MacOS in a VM on older hardware. The VM still sees the same (unsupported) CPU.

Comment: I was able to download the main files, the 7GB InstallESDDmg.pkg and the others thanks to _gibMacOS_, but then the Catalina patcher doesn't recognize the installer app.
Also tried to burn the DMGs to USB and boot from there, but didn't work either.